# Question on rank function.

Tags: commutative-algebra

In a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090341/fiber-as-vector-space-over-residue-field) I asked about the fiber $M(P)=M_P / PM_P$ where $M$ is an $A$-module and $P$ a prime ideal of $A$. Later I introduced the rank function $$rk_M : \text{Spec} A \to \mathbb{N} \cup \{ \infty \}$$ given by $$P \mapsto \dim_{A(P)} M(P).$$ I am supposed to prove that if $M$ is finitely generated then $rk_M(P)$ is finite and $rk_M(P) > 0$ iff $P \in \text{Supp}(M)$. I managed to prove everything expect the last implication $P \in \text{Supp}(M) \implies rk_M(P) > 0$, I am stuck on this one although I feel it should not be hard, any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its easy: if $P \in Supp(M)$, then $M(P)$ is a non-zero $A(P)$-vector space. For it were the zero space then we would have $M_P = P M_P$ and Nakayama's Lemma would imply $M_P=0$. But this contradicts the assumption that $P \in Supp(M)$. Thus $M(P)$ must have a positive dimension.

Comment: Can I ask a question related to this one quick? I dont want to start a new thread, I want to know if a statement I made is true.

Comment: Give an example of a ring $A$ and an $A$-module $M$ with $rk_M(P)=0$ but $P \in Supp(M)$. I chose $A= \mathbb{Z}$ and $M= \mathbb{R}$, and the prime ideal $(2) \in Supp(\mathbb{Z})$. Is this example ok? I was unsure about one step I took in proving it.

Comment: @Sodan: This should be a new post. Please start one and add what you did, where are you stuck and why.

Comment: Hmm ok, do you see something wrong with the example right away?

Comment: Its unclear: What is $rk_M(P)$?

Comment: In our case i chose $P=(2)$ so that $rk_M(P)= dim_{A(P)}M(P)$, however $M(P)=M_P/PM_P$ and since $M_P=PM_P$ we have that $M(P)$ only consist of the zero element, hence its dimension over $A(P)$ must be zero, that is, $rk_M(P)=0$-

Answer (score 0):

It results from Nakayama's lemma: if $A$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ and $M$ is a finitely generated $A$-module, then $$M/\mathfrak m M=0 \Rightarrow M=0.$$